# How do I make a video fit the device dimensions in full screen landscape mode?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a Card with smaller dimensions than the screen size, and its child has this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: screenHeight * 0.03,
              ),

              SizedBox(
                width: screenWidth * 0.85,
                height: screenHeight * 0.68,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: home.youtubeControllers.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
                          child: Text(
                            home.videoTitles[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
                          child: Text(
                            home.videoUploadDates[index],
                          ),
                        ),

                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 15, left: 25, right: 25),
                          child: YoutubePlayerScaffold(
                            controller: home.youtubeControllers[index],
                            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                            builder: (context, player) {
                              return player;
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_iframe.

When I click on the fullscreen button, the problem is all the other widgets can also be seen and the video is within the card still, it does not expand into the whole screen like the YouTube app.

How do I mimic the YouTube fullscreen functionality when my video is a smaller size and inside a Card?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, here's what I did:

Where I assigned the controller, after that statement I overrided the `onFullscreenChange` method of this package:

```
controller.onFullscreenChange = (isFullScreen) {
          currentYoutubeController = controller;
};
```

As you can see, `currentYoutubeController` is an new variable to hold the current video's controller, so if that is clicked for fullscreen, we have the controller with us and know which video was opened in the list.

Lastly, I placed an `OrientationBuilder` in the `Scaffold` `body` section. Here it checks if it is landscape, and if it is, I return **only** the YoutubePlayer widget. So it takes the whole screen.